# Orange release notes

Tags: orange

What is the best way to understand changes made in new releases? For example, Orange 3.21 came out recently and I’m eager to understand any prominent fixes or modified features.

Answer (score 2):

All release notes for new versions of the Orange Data Mining software can be found by looking at the release page on its GitHub page [here](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/releases). Then just navigate to the most recent release and click on the latest branch. This will display a window similar to the following where you can view all of the changes that were made (both enhancements and bug fixes) in the most recent update.

Snapshot for Orange 3.21.0 below:

[image]

Comment: You can also look into the changelog file on the relevant tag directly: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/3.21.0/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @K3---rnc Yes, this also works. Great point.